# Does Castle of Illusion support Bluetooth controllers on iPad?

Tags: controllers, ios, castle-of-illusion-2013

I am interested in purchasing "Castle of Illusion Starring Mickey Mouse" for iPadOS.  The game is quite old (2013) and does not list support for a controller.  However I have read comments that others were able to control the game with a keyboard.

Is it possible to play and control "Castle of Illusion" with a bluetooth controller, even if it's not listed as compatible with controllers?

Comment: I don't own the game on iOS/iPadOS, but since that game was also released in Windows and OSX, that comment you've read could possibly be indicating that they've played on PC... I'm not sure though.